# const qualifier for a string literal

Tags: c++, string, constants

I have the following code which I wrote to test the const member function:
It compiles and runs fine when I have the const qualifier for the data member 
char *data and to the argument for the constructor. However if I remove const from
the data member and the constructor, i get compiler error.
Is it because the string "Hello World" is always of type const char * ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class mystring {
        const char *data;
        mutable int length;
        mutable int valid;
public:
        mystring(const char *str) {data = str;}
        ~mystring() { };
        int GetLength() const;
};

int mystring::GetLength() const
{
        if (valid)
                return length;
        else {
                length = strlen(data);
                valid = 1;
                return length;
        }
}

int main()
{
        const char *str = "Hello World";

        mystring s(str);

        cout << s.GetLength() << endl;
}
```

Comment: When you remove the const qualification, do you also remove it from the declaration of `str` in `main`?

Comment: Originally I was declaring str as mystring s = "Hello World";

Comment: `mystring s = "Hello World"` will compile perfectly fine with your code even if you remove `const` as you describe in your question. Also, when you have problems with "compiler errors", you have to post the exact errors you are getting. Nobody here is telepathic.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `const` from the constructor, it is telling callers that it expects to take a `char*` as a parameter and might change the `char` at the end of the pointer.

Because you are constructing mystring with a `const char*`, the compiler is raising an error to help ensure your code does what it expects to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to construct a mystring with a `const char*` when it wants a `char*` as its parameter. You cannot go from const to non const without a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, string literals in C++ are of type `const char *`.

To treat it as `char *`, you need to do `const_cast<char*>(str)`. This is probably a bad idea though - modifying a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: And the undefined behavior is usually to crash with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Firstly, string literals in C++ are *not* of type `const char *`. String literals in C++ have type `const char[N]`. Secondly, C++ language allows [deprecated] implicit conversion of string literals to type `char *`, meaning that there's no need for `const_cast` to treat a string literal as `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `const` from the constructor parameter and from the data member, the code will not compile because the argument `str` you are passing to your constructor is declared as `const char *`. It has absolutely nothing to do with `"Hello World"` literal at all. You can initialize your `str` with `0` instead of `"Hello World"`, and the code will still fail to compile.

String literal `"Hello World"` has type `const char[12]`. However , language rules allow converting string literals to `char *` type, which means that if you initialized your object as

```
mystring s("Hello World");
```

the code would compile fine even after you removed `const` from the constructor parameter and from the data member. But once you throw that intermediate variable `str` into the picture `"Hello World"` becomes irrelevant. It doesn't matter anymore what `"Hello World"` is. Only what `str` is matters.

Comment: No I did not have the intermediate variable str first. I had mystring s = "Hello World"; and no const in the data member or constructor argument and the code failed to compile.

Comment: @avi: The code you posted above will compile perfectly fine *without* `const` with both `mystring s = "Hello World"` or `mystring s("Hello World")`, which means that either you are posting fake code or simply not paying attention to what you are doing. If you are really getting errors from `mystring s = "Hello World"` - post real code, since what you posted above is fake.

Comment: #include <iostream> #include <string.h> using namespace std; class mystring { char *data; mutable int length; mutable int valid; public: mystring(char *str) {data = str;} ~mystring() { }; int GetLength(); }; int mystring::GetLength() { if (valid) return length; else { length = strlen(data); valid = 1; return length; } } int main() { mystring s("Hello World"); cout << s.GetLength() << endl; } This is the actual code which doesn't compile.

Comment: @avi: This code compiles fine by every compiler I tried. What compiler are you trying to use?